# Thymeleaf could not parse as expression th:select option

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I just can't figure out my error. Here's my updateprofile.html.

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" th:value = "${user.team}" id="team" name="team" roleId="team" required="required">
    <option disabled="disabled">Select your team</option>
    <option th:selected="${user.team} == 'A'}">A</option>
    <option th:selected="${user.team} == 'B'}">B</option>
    <option th:selected="${user.team} == 'C'}">C</option>
    <option th:selected="${user.team} == 'D'}">D</option>  
    <option th:selected="${user.team} == 'TSO'}">TSO</option>   
</select>
```

The error is

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as expression: "${user.team} == 'A'}" (updateprofile:54)

Here is my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateprofile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateProfile(Principal principal, Model model) {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "updateprofile";
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `}` in your thymeleaf expression.

Try this

`<option th:selected="${user.team} == 'A'">A</option>`